# sizeof initialized constant in c

Tags: c, sizeof

I have write simple example code ([also available at ideone](https://ideone.com/JJY4kG)) to show where I have found problem. Sizeof return erroneous result in case of constant `s`. Bellow is file `main.c`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// comment this option if you know what is UB and want to avoit it 
#define I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_IS_UB ( 1 )

struct _sa {
    uint32_t w;
    uint8_t const a[];
};

uint8_t const a[] = { 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };

struct _sa const s = {
    .w = 8,
    .a = { 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 },
};

char const b[] = "line";

int main(void)
{
    #ifdef I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_IS_UB
    printf("sizeof(a) = %d \n", (int)sizeof(a)); // = 8
    printf("sizeof(s) = %d \n", (int)sizeof(s)); // = 4
    printf("sizeof(b) = %d \n", (int)sizeof(b)); // = 5
    #else
    printf("sizeof(a) = %zu \n", sizeof(a)); // = 8
    printf("sizeof(s) = %zu \n", sizeof(s)); // = 4
    printf("sizeof(b) = %zu \n", sizeof(b)); // = 5
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

I use aged ubuntu:

```
uname -a
Linux imbearr 4.4.0-148-generic #174~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 9 08:17:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~14.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcc main.c -o szof -Xlinker -Map=szof.map
grep -C 1 "\bs\b" ./szof.map 
                0x00000000004005e8                a
                0x00000000004005f0                s
                0x00000000004005fc                b
```

So I have checked sizes via linker map files:
0x4005fc - 0x4005f0 = 12,
0x4005f0 - 0x4005e8 = 8.

Why I have such results, is this gcc limitations or bug, may be this is my mistake?

Comment: According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html): _Flexible array members have incomplete type, and so the sizeof operator may not be applied_

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: The code in the question does not apply the `sizeof` operator to a flexible array member. It applies it to the entire structure, which is allowed and defined.

Comment: shouldn't `size_t` be printed with `%zu` to avoid UB? because `sizeof` returns `size_t` and not an integer.

Comment: @Shark I'm pretty understand your note (I have seen same problems in practice) and you are really right... But who are really know what is UB besides of you?

Comment: Here's an example of what made me really fear UB (undefined behaviour) - methods not returning on a return statement, and code just keeping on executing downwards. This method that was causing UB (or something that was causing it) was actually crashing 3 methods below it, in part of the code that should logically not even run. You're free to do as you like though.

Comment: @Shark, thank you for description to "what i's UB". Of course undefined behaviour it is the fear for every programmer, and it's good manner to write clear code that not depend on arch. I'll read carefully read man for printf for future use. But for now, for one project and in condition of custom printf implementation this have no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking for the size of a structure with a flexible array member gives only the base size of the structure, without the array member. C 2018 6.7.2.1 18 says:

> … In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply…

Thus, `sizeof s` is the size the structure would have if the flexible array member `a` were not present, except it may have extra padding. Since the `uint32_t w;` member requires four bytes, and your compiler does not insert extra padding in this case, the size of the structure is four bytes.

### Note

The extra padding arises in cases like this:

```
struct foo
{
    char c;
    int array[];
};
```

In an implementation where `int` requires four-byte alignment, the compiler will ensure the array member is aligned by inserting three bytes after member `c`, so `sizeof (struct foo)` will be four.

Comment: what about `#pragma pack` ?

Comment: @Shark: What about it?

Comment: would it not change the size by adding or omitting padding? however, i'm gonna be honest, i don't quite know where i was going with it, except that mentioning it and the golden rule of "ordering struct members from biggest to smallest by hand". but `#pragma pack 2` could reduce the `struct foo`'s size to 2 for example.

Comment: @Shark: The question asks why the size of the structure is reported as it is. It does not ask to change the size or the structure. If the structure were packed, it would be a different structure with a possibly different size, but the question does not seem to involve that. In fact, since the OP is getting 4 for a structure with a four-byte `uint32_t` member, there is no padding, so asking for this structure to be packed would not change its size (just its alignment requirement).

Comment: right, hence the "i dont know where i was going with that comment" :)

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof` returns the size of the type of the parameter.

So when you call `sizeof(b)`, you're really asking, "*What is the size of `struct _sa`?*"

The size of `struct _sa` is 4 bytes, because element `.w` takes up 4 bytes, and element `.a` is a flexible array that takes up zero-bytes, because the array, as defined in the type, does not have a defined size.

Comment: It's not just size of type: `sizeof("string") == 7` - there six chars and one trailing null byte each `sizeof(char) == 1`. So `sizeof(variable) == sizeof(type) * count` but this is not working for flexible arrays inside struct.

Comment: The type of `"string"` is not a `char`; it's type is a `char[7]`, which is 7 bytes long.

Comment: ops.. you are really right. And thus your answer is correct too. I'll keep selection as is (because asnwer of Eric is more full) and vote up your answer.